# how can i compare integer values from the vector?

Tags: java, compare

in this example it prints out Student's names and credits what users enter from keyboard to the Vector.

but i wanna only print out Vectors which has credits more than 30.

thanks for any help.

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Teacher t = new Teacher("Prof. Smith", "F020");
       Student s = new Student("Gipsz Jakab", 34);


       Vector<Person> pv = new Vector<Person>(); 
       pv.add(t);
       pv.add(s);

       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String name;
       int credits;


       for (int i=0;i<5;i++){

         System.out.print("Name: ");
         name = sc.nextLine();
         System.out.print("Credits: ");
         credits = sc.nextInt(); 
         sc.skip("\n"); 

         pv.add(new Student(name, credits));
       }
       System.out.println(pv); 
       System.out.println("The size of the Vector is: " + pv.size()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: use get(..) to get the value and compare using if.

Comment: can a user enter any string as credit ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
if (credits > 30){
    pv.add(new Student(name, credits));
}
```

instead of:

```
pv.add(new Student(name, credits));
```

Comment: Then asnwer should be an answer not a question. ;-).

Answer (score 1):

You should/must use an Iterator, the simple way to do it is:

```
Iterator it = pv .iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Student s= it.next();
    if(s.credits>30) System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [if statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html). To check that credists is greated than 30.

```
if (x > n ) {
 // this block of code will be executed when x is greated then n.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check before you add to the vector. Out of interest any reason you are using a vector and not an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
 for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
     System.out.print("Name: ");
     name = sc.nextLine();
     System.out.print("Credits: ");
     credits = sc.nextInt(); 
     sc.skip("\n"); 

     if (credits >= 30) { //this additional check is needed
          pv.add(new Student(name, credits));
      } 
 }
```